# OOB score for single tree of a Random Forest classifier in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

The `oob_score_` method  is available in sklearn's for the full `RandomForestClassifier` ensemble. However I am interested in the OOB score of *every* tree of the ensemble. It seems to me that such information gets lost in the averaging step performed. As a consequence, what is reported in the `oob_score_` and `oob_decision_function_` methods don't have the information I need.

In other words, instead of taking the average OOB score across trees given a single sample, I am interested in the average OOB error of a single tree across the left-out samples. I am aware that such average will be performed across differing samples but this is not an issue.

Comment: Please include a *question*.

Comment: Does the answer have to be within `scikit-learn`'s API? If so, that is impossible.